# Tensorflow tf.map_fn error throws type error

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to parallelize convolution on an image input using tf.map_fn

```
def convolution(inp):
    return tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=inp[0],filters =32, kernel_size = inp[1])


 data = np.array([(x,(3,3)),(x,(5,5)),(x,(7,7))])
 L = tf.map_fn(convolution,data,dtype = tf.float32)
```

But this throws me an error saying,

> Blockquote TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 480, 640, 3) dtype=float32

How can I sort this out? Is there any other way to efficiently parallelize the convolution operations on the same input for different kernel sizes?

Comment: `conv2d` operations are already parallelized (if possible) on GPU/CPU. Using `tf.map_fn` would only slow down these operations by adding a lot of small operations to the execution.